# Can I install Samsung 960 EVO on Lenovo Y520 as a storage drive separately without installing any OS on it and not use it for booting?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, hardware-detection

My laptop came with a 128 GB SSD (SATA) and a 1 TB HDD but after installing the OS and all the softwares I need, I am barely left with 50 GB on the SSD which isn't enough for gaming (GTA V itself is 65 GB) and I don't want to install games on the 5400 RPM HDD. I saw a couple of installation videos on youtube and I'm wondering if I can I add a 250 GB Samsung 960 EVO just for storage without installing any OS on it? Would it require some BIOS configuration? Would Windows read it as a storage drive? I just need to make sure before I buy it.

Comment: Add? you mean replace the 1tb with ssd? Sure can, it will be seen the same as the 1tb drive, a mass storage device.

Comment: Nope. Not replace. Add the m.2 SSD in it's own slot without removing any other drive. I would be having 3 drives after that then. The HDD as a storage device, the 128 GB SSD with the OS and the Samsung 960 EVO m.2 NVME SSD for storage again.